# Django urls "overlapping"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I googled this problem and didn't find anything that would help.

Here comes my project structure:

```
-myproject
  -controlpanel
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    -templates
       -controlpanel
          -index.html
       -include
          -navbar.html

  -main
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    -templates
       -main
          -index.html
       -partials
          -navbar.html

  -myproject
    -urls.py
```

And this is my controlpanel urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('servers', views.servers, name='servers'),
]
```

This is my main urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('join', views.join, name='join'),
    path('rules', views.rules, name='rules'),
    path('services', views.services, name='services'),
    path('stats', views.stats, name='stats'),
    path('gdpr', views.gdpr, name='gdpr'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

This is myproject urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('controlpanel/', include('controlpanel.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Now when a user doesn't specify any subdirectory he should be redirected to index.html in app main.

The problem is that some {% url 'urlname' %} return urls from other projects. For instance when i used {% url 'index' %} in main apps navbar it used url controlpanel/index which it isn't supposed to do.

This also happened to me when I was creating a navbar for controlpanel and imported CSS but I solved it by renaming the folder to "include". I would generally just rename files to fix it to something like index > home, etc.. but this app is supposed to be copied to existing projects and I don't want to do it in this dirty way.

I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have suspected Django can tackle this problem easily, you can see some examples for this in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

In every urls.py file you can specify an 'app_name'. In your case you could do something the following:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'controlpanel'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('servers', views.servers, name='servers'),
]
```

Second urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('join', views.join, name='join'),
    path('rules', views.rules, name='rules'),
    ...
]
```

now in any reverse or url template tag you can include the app name like this:

```
{% url 'main:index' %}
{% url 'controlpanel:index' %}
```

Django will now know where to look for the 'name' index